# How to get sender IP when uploading a blob within the Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions, ip, ip-address

I have the default blob trigger function within my function app. If I give someone R/W access to a container within my storage account and they upload a blob file, I want to print out who sent the file - specifically their IP address - or some other identifying characteristic. I have gone through the $logs directory as I saw on a different post that the sender IP would be there, but it was not. Does anyone know how to get the sender IP?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's possible to get a caller ip by activating diagnostic settings (preview). I've send logs to log analytics workspace and here is demo query

```
StorageBlobLogs
| project CallerIpAddress, AccountName, OperationName, StatusText
```